# Convert code to increment by Minutes and Hours rather than 100

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am trying to convert this block of code to increment like time and minutes (0-60) instead of counting and changing when it hits 100. This is run from a button that adds 1, 5, or 10 to the score.  The MC contains three child MC's of digits, each one with a text field that has 10 frames that changes it from 0-9.  It works perfect as it is, but I want the 100th digit (or digit3) to change to 1 when the first two digits reach 60 instead of 99.  I Can't figure out how I need to incorporate this into the code.  Any help would be appreciated.  I might even need to rewrite the whole thing.

```
var SPEED:int = 1;// how fast to count
var NUM_DIGITS:int = 3;// how many digits are there in the score

var _totalScore:int = 0;
var _displayScore:int = 0;


// add an amount to the score
function add(amount:int):void
{
    _totalScore +=  amount;
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, updateScoreDisplay);// start the display counting up
}

// this runs every frame to update the score
function updateScoreDisplay(e:Event):void
{

    // increment the display score by the speed amount
    _displayScore +=  SPEED;

    // make sure the display score is not higher than the actual score
    if (_displayScore > _totalScore)
    {
        _displayScore = _totalScore;
    }

    var scoreStr:String = String(_displayScore);// cast displayScore as a String

    // add leading zeros
    while (scoreStr.length < NUM_DIGITS)
    {
        scoreStr = "0" + scoreStr;
    }

    // loop through and update each digit
    for (var i:int = 0; i < NUM_DIGITS; i++)
    {
        var num = int(scoreStr.charAt(i));

        this["digit" + (i + 1)].gotoAndStop(num+1);

    }
    // set the digit mc to the right frame;
    // if the display score is equal to the total score remove the enterframe event
    if (_totalScore == _displayScore)
    {
    removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, updateScoreDisplay);
    }
}
```

Comment: "*each one with a text field that has 10 frames that changes it from 0-9.*" Why not assign text dynamically and have only one frame?

Answer (score 1):

Are you changing the actual calculated score? Or just the label that displays the score?

If you want to keep the calculated score as a normal number but only change the way you display it, use this:

```
var seconds:String = (_displayScore % 60).toString();
var minutes:String = Math.floor(_displayScore / 60).toString();
if(seconds.length == 1)
    seconds = "0" + seconds;

var scoreStr:String = minutes + seconds;
```

Comment: Now I was thinking about doing it dynamically... Saw the post before yours.  I was really just trying to find an easy way to input a set time for a time...display it in a fun way, and then have it countdown.

Comment: var SPEED:int = 1; // how fast to count
var totalTime:int = 0;
var currentTime:int = 0;
var value:int;


// add an amount to the score
function add(amount:int):void
{
 totalTime +=  amount;
 value = amount;
 
 
 for (var i:int = 0; i < value; i++)
 {
  var currentValue:int = currentTime + 1;
  digit3.txtNum.text = currentValue.toString();
  currentTime = currentTime + 1;
 }
 
 if (currentTime == totalTime)
 {
  trace ("We are the same!");
 }
}

Comment: @user2957919 please don't post code in comments. Add it to your question instead.

Comment: Yes the text should absolutely be dynamic, but even with dynamic text, you're still going to have to convert it if you want it to increment by minutes

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather rewrite the above to something that fits your current requirements. 
Here's an example:

Main.as

```
package {

import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;

[SWF(frameRate="24", backgroundColor="#FFFFFF", width="400", height="240")]
public class Main extends Sprite {

    private static const STOP_AT_HOUR:uint = 2;
    private static const STOP_AT_MINUTES:uint = 31;

    public function Main() {
        var tracker:Tracker = new Tracker();
        startTracking(tracker, STOP_AT_HOUR, STOP_AT_MINUTES,
                function onTrackingProgress(tracker:Tracker):void {
                    updateVisualElements(tracker);
                });
    }

    private function startTracking(tracker:Tracker, stopAtHour:uint, stopAtMinutes:uint, onProgress:Function):void {
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, function onEnterFrame(event:Event):void {
            onProgress(tracker.increment());
            if (tracker.hours == stopAtHour && tracker.minutes == stopAtMinutes) {
                removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);
                trace("Maximum bounds have been reached; tracking stopped.");
            }
        });
    }

    private function updateVisualElements(tracker:Tracker):void {
        var hoursString: String =  appendLeadingZero(tracker.hours);
        var minutesString:String = appendLeadingZero(tracker.minutes);
        trace("Tracked time: " + hoursString + ":" + minutesString);

        try {
            // update visual elements that display hour
            this["digit0"].gotoAndPlay(uint(hoursString.charAt(0)) + 1);
            this["digit1"].gotoAndPlay(uint(hoursString.charAt(1)) + 1);

            // update visual elements that display minutes
            this["digit2"].gotoAndPlay(uint(minutesString.charAt(0)) + 1);
            this["digit3"].gotoAndPlay(uint(minutesString.charAt(1)) + 1);

        } catch (error: Error) {
            // does not work because there are no visual elements named "digit0", "digit1", "digit2", "digit3"
            // in this example; the above code is purely demonstrative to show how such visual elements 
            // could be updated using the tracker information
        }
    }

    private function appendLeadingZero(temporalValue:uint):String {
        if (temporalValue >= 100) throw new ArgumentError("Implementation missing for values above 99");
        return temporalValue < 10 ? String("0" + temporalValue) : String(temporalValue);
    }
}
}
```

Tracker.as

```
package {

public class Tracker {

    private var _hours:uint = 0;
    private var _minutes:uint = 0;

    private var minutesResetValue:uint;

    public function Tracker(minutesResetValue:uint = 60) {
        this.minutesResetValue = minutesResetValue;
    }

    public function increment():Tracker {
        _minutes++;
        if (_minutes == minutesResetValue) {
            _minutes = 0;
            _hours++;
        }
        return this;
    }

    public function get hours():uint {
        return _hours;
    }

    public function get minutes():uint {
        return _minutes;
    }
}
}
```

Running the above code would output:

```
[trace] Tracked time: 00:01
[trace] Tracked time: 00:02
[trace] Tracked time: 00:03
[trace] Tracked time: 00:04
[trace] Tracked time: 00:05
[trace] Tracked time: 00:06
[trace] Tracked time: 00:07
[trace] Tracked time: 00:08
[trace] Tracked time: 00:09
[trace] Tracked time: 00:10
[trace] Tracked time: 00:11
[trace] Tracked time: 00:12
[trace] Tracked time: 00:13
[trace] Tracked time: 00:14
[trace] Tracked time: 00:15
[trace] Tracked time: 00:16
[trace] Tracked time: 00:17
[trace] Tracked time: 00:18
[trace] Tracked time: 00:19
[trace] Tracked time: 00:20
[trace] Tracked time: 00:21
[trace] Tracked time: 00:22
[trace] Tracked time: 00:23
[trace] Tracked time: 00:24
[trace] Tracked time: 00:25
[trace] Tracked time: 00:26
[trace] Tracked time: 00:27
[trace] Tracked time: 00:28
[trace] Tracked time: 00:29
[trace] Tracked time: 00:30
[trace] Tracked time: 00:31
[trace] Tracked time: 00:32
[trace] Tracked time: 00:33
[trace] Tracked time: 00:34
[trace] Tracked time: 00:35
[trace] Tracked time: 00:36
[trace] Tracked time: 00:37
[trace] Tracked time: 00:38
[trace] Tracked time: 00:39
[trace] Tracked time: 00:40
[trace] Tracked time: 00:41
[trace] Tracked time: 00:42
[trace] Tracked time: 00:43
[trace] Tracked time: 00:44
[trace] Tracked time: 00:45
[trace] Tracked time: 00:46
[trace] Tracked time: 00:47
[trace] Tracked time: 00:48
[trace] Tracked time: 00:49
[trace] Tracked time: 00:50
[trace] Tracked time: 00:51
[trace] Tracked time: 00:52
[trace] Tracked time: 00:53
[trace] Tracked time: 00:54
[trace] Tracked time: 00:55
[trace] Tracked time: 00:56
[trace] Tracked time: 00:57
[trace] Tracked time: 00:58
[trace] Tracked time: 00:59
[trace] Tracked time: 01:00
[trace] Tracked time: 01:01
[trace] Tracked time: 01:02
[trace] Tracked time: 01:03
[trace] Tracked time: 01:04
[trace] Tracked time: 01:05
[trace] Tracked time: 01:06
[trace] Tracked time: 01:07
[trace] Tracked time: 01:08
[trace] Tracked time: 01:09
[trace] Tracked time: 01:10
[trace] Tracked time: 01:11
[trace] Tracked time: 01:12
[trace] Tracked time: 01:13
[trace] Tracked time: 01:14
[trace] Tracked time: 01:15
[trace] Tracked time: 01:16
[trace] Tracked time: 01:17
[trace] Tracked time: 01:18
[trace] Tracked time: 01:19
[trace] Tracked time: 01:20
[trace] Tracked time: 01:21
[trace] Tracked time: 01:22
[trace] Tracked time: 01:23
[trace] Tracked time: 01:24
[trace] Tracked time: 01:25
[trace] Tracked time: 01:26
[trace] Tracked time: 01:27
[trace] Tracked time: 01:28
[trace] Tracked time: 01:29
[trace] Tracked time: 01:30
[trace] Tracked time: 01:31
[trace] Tracked time: 01:32
[trace] Tracked time: 01:33
[trace] Tracked time: 01:34
[trace] Tracked time: 01:35
[trace] Tracked time: 01:36
[trace] Tracked time: 01:37
[trace] Tracked time: 01:38
[trace] Tracked time: 01:39
[trace] Tracked time: 01:40
[trace] Tracked time: 01:41
[trace] Tracked time: 01:42
[trace] Tracked time: 01:43
[trace] Tracked time: 01:44
[trace] Tracked time: 01:45
[trace] Tracked time: 01:46
[trace] Tracked time: 01:47
[trace] Tracked time: 01:48
[trace] Tracked time: 01:49
[trace] Tracked time: 01:50
[trace] Tracked time: 01:51
[trace] Tracked time: 01:52
[trace] Tracked time: 01:53
[trace] Tracked time: 01:54
[trace] Tracked time: 01:55
[trace] Tracked time: 01:56
[trace] Tracked time: 01:57
[trace] Tracked time: 01:58
[trace] Tracked time: 01:59
[trace] Tracked time: 02:00
[trace] Tracked time: 02:01
[trace] Tracked time: 02:02
[trace] Tracked time: 02:03
[trace] Tracked time: 02:04
[trace] Tracked time: 02:05
[trace] Tracked time: 02:06
[trace] Tracked time: 02:07
[trace] Tracked time: 02:08
[trace] Tracked time: 02:09
[trace] Tracked time: 02:10
[trace] Tracked time: 02:11
[trace] Tracked time: 02:12
[trace] Tracked time: 02:13
[trace] Tracked time: 02:14
[trace] Tracked time: 02:15
[trace] Tracked time: 02:16
[trace] Tracked time: 02:17
[trace] Tracked time: 02:18
[trace] Tracked time: 02:19
[trace] Tracked time: 02:20
[trace] Tracked time: 02:21
[trace] Tracked time: 02:22
[trace] Tracked time: 02:23
[trace] Tracked time: 02:24
[trace] Tracked time: 02:25
[trace] Tracked time: 02:26
[trace] Tracked time: 02:27
[trace] Tracked time: 02:28
[trace] Tracked time: 02:29
[trace] Tracked time: 02:30
[trace] Tracked time: 02:31
[trace] Maximum bounds have been reached; tracking stopped.
```